# Generate TestCases for Methods based on its Signature using CodeDom in C#

Tags: c#

Consider the following Code snippet,

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(DLL_Path);
Type t = asm.GetType(DLL_NameSpace.MyClass, false, true);
clsMethodInvoke mi = new clsMethodInvoke();
foreach (MemberInfo oMember in t.GetMembers(mi.GetFilter()))
{
                                //code here
}
```

These are the values in the follwing variables,

```
t = {Name = "Class1" FullName = "a.Class1"}
oMember = {Int32 add(Int32, Int32)}
```

Now from these values i need to Generate NUnit based TestCases as follows,

```
[Test()]
public virtual void Testadd1() {
    Class1 Class1 = new Class1();

    int a = -1; //random values are stored here
    int b = 2147483647; //random values are stored here

}
```

So having the type of the Class in an Assembly i want to generate test cases for each method, as show above. How can i generate such Test Cases.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Pex](http://www.codeplex.com/Pex), which is a tool for generating unit tests from analysis of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using T4?

Article:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Templates:
http://www.codeplex.com/t4toolbox

Editor:
http://www.visualt4.com/

In terms of the technicalities of how to construct the code I'm not sure what you mean when you refer to:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(DLL_Path);
Type t = asm.GetType(DLL_NameSpace.MyClass, false, true);
clsMethodInvoke mi = new clsMethodInvoke();
foreach (MemberInfo oMember in t.GetMembers(mi.GetFilter()))
{
    string parameters = GetParameters(oMember);
    string test = String.Format(testTemplate, t.Name, m.Name, parameters);
    // Feed test string to T4.
}
```

Then testTemplate would be:

```
[Test()]
public virtual void Test{0}{1}() {
    {0} test{0} = new {0}();

    {2}
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate this solution... am not able to understand this..am new to codedom